# docker - installing java 8 with curl

Tags: java, docker

To insall java 8 on docker container, I used this command in dockerfile

```
RUN curl -LO 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.rpm'
-H 'Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' RUN rpm -i jdk-8u111-linux-x64.rpm RUN rm jdk-8u111-linux-x64.rpm
```

It worked for awhile, but now this link is not no longer available. Is there replaceable url for this? or easy way to insall java 8 on docker?

Comment: Note: http://blog.takipi.com/running-java-on-docker-youre-breaking-the-law/

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your using OS, so I'd like you to show your OS.  For example, Ubuntu users prepares their ppa repository for Oracle Java.

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Oracle has changed the authorization for downloading, the actual link that the browser uses is http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.rpm?AuthParam=1496223138_c808095f7637d83147c37d69d3a87e7a, but this cannot be used with curl.

I have no solution for the problem with downloading from Oracle, but I use the [official OpenJDK image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) as base and have found no problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

If openjdk is OK for you, you can use

```
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

openjdk, in contrast to oracle, does not require user's confirmation.

If you only need java runtime, consider `openjdk-8-jre`.

Answer (score 0):

Adaption of my Dockerfile from https://hub.docker.com/r/sftech/java

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV JAVA_VERSION=8

RUN echo oracle-java${JAVA_VERSION}-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
 && apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y oracle-java${JAVA_VERSION}-installer \
 && update-java-alternatives -s java-${JAVA_VERSION}-oracle \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you install java in an image / container, when you can get a [java:8 image from the Docker store](https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-serverjre-8) for free. The license requirements are exactly the same as the java / jdk download install from the oracle.com website.